# StringUtils in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, utilities

I'm looking for a js library like [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) of commons-lang in java, which contains a lot of common methods to operating strings.

Such as:

- IsEmpty/IsBlank - checks if a String contains text
- Trim/Strip - removes leading and trailing whitespace
- Equals - compares two strings null-safe
- startsWith - check if a String starts with a prefix null-safe
- endsWith - check if a String ends with a suffix null-safe
- IndexOf/LastIndexOf/Contains - null-safe index-of checks
- IndexOfAny/LastIndexOfAny/IndexOfAnyBut/LastIndexOfAnyBut - index-of any of a set of Strings
- ContainsOnly/ContainsNone/ContainsAny - does String contains only/none/any of these characters
- Substring/Left/Right/Mid - null-safe substring extractions
- SubstringBefore/SubstringAfter/SubstringBetween - substring extraction relative to other strings
- Split/Join - splits a String into an array of substrings and vice versa
- Remove/Delete - removes part of a String
- Replace/Overlay - Searches a String and replaces one String with another
- Chomp/Chop - removes the last part of a String
- LeftPad/RightPad/Center/Repeat - pads a String
- UpperCase/LowerCase/SwapCase/Capitalize/Uncapitalize - changes the case of a String
- CountMatches - counts the number of occurrences of one String in another
- IsAlpha/IsNumeric/IsWhitespace/IsAsciiPrintable - checks the characters in a String
- DefaultString - protects against a null input String
- Reverse/ReverseDelimited - reverses a String
- Abbreviate - abbreviates a string using ellipsis

It'll be better if it contains some other methods for arrays/date, etc.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the operations you want to perform on strings?

Comment: Please provide a link to the documentation of the `StringUtils` API. JavaScript programmers usually don't have much experience with Java, so they don't know what methods `StringUtils` provides...

Comment: Already added the link to `StringUtils`

Comment: @Freewind From what I can see, many of the `StringUtils` static methods are available in JavaScript as instance methods. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2

Comment: please note that some functions, like startsWith/endsWith are not supporte by IE :-(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

String utils - [Underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string)

Object/array utils - [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)

Date utils - [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Comment: Good, the underscore.string is just what I'm looking for

Comment: @timrwood: any idea about the browser support ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424011/underscore-string-browser-support

Comment: Note from the authors of moment.js: "_we would like to discourage Moment from being used in new projects going forward_" ([source](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)).

Answer (score 12):

Here we go:

**IsEmpty**

```
str.length === 0
```

**IsBlank**

```
str.trim().length === 0
```

**Trim**

```
str.trim()
```

**Equals**

```
str1 === str2
```

**startsWith**

```
str.indexOf( str2 ) === 0
```

**IndexOf**

```
str.indexOf( str2 )
```

**LastIndexOf**

```
str.lastIndexOf( str2 )
```

**Contains**

```
str.indexOf( str2 ) !== -1
```

**Substring**

```
str.substring( start, end )
```

**Left**

```
str.slice( 0, len )
```

**Mid**

```
str.substr( i, len )
```

**Right**

```
str.slice( -len, str.length )
```

And so on... (should I continue?)

Comment: Javascript can be a nightmare when it comes to code portability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript/8522376#8522376

Comment: @Redger `trim()` is the exception here. The other string methods are cross-browser.

Comment: commons-lang `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` is `null` resistant here and there, for example `isEmpty` is implemented like this `return str == null || str.length() == 0;`

Comment: although this answer is relevant as it demonstrates it's not "that hard" to compare with native JS, one might argue that if u only occasionally do JS development u might want to use a JS Util library to avoid silly mistakes & time-consuming learning. This is the goal of this library, see [the introduction statement on Undescorejs.org](underscorejs.org). This subset of underscore.js [github.com/epeli/underscore.string](underscore.string.js) is only 7Kb once minified (NOT gzipped!). The only problem I can see is the browser support being unclear, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10657313/759452

Comment: correction: underscore.string is `"an extension for Underscore.js"` (it is not "a subset of underscore.js"), but you can use it as a [`"Standalone Usage"` (without underscore.js)](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#standalone-usage)

Answer (score 1):

Use both Javascript basic methods and JQuery for DOM and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for dates.

Read this: [Utils library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681173/javascript-is-there-a-utils-library) if you're looking for compatibility between browsers.

Or you can write your own Apache-like commons-lang too!

Comment: jQuery for operations on primitive values....?

Comment: Dates? The question is a about string operations...

Comment: He said : "It'll be better if it contains some other methods for arrays/date, etc." so basic Javascript methods for strings, JQuery for advanced handling of DOM and JSON (all strings after all) and moment.js for date parsing (strings too).

Comment: I also mentioned `date` in the last part of the question :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm constantly switching between Java backend and JavaScript frontend so for me it makes a lot of sense just to blindly use the StringUtils methods and don't even think about it. It would be great if someone would take the time to port all of the Apache StringUtils methods into a JavaScript ;-)

Here's my contribution:

```
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(prefix) {
    return this.indexOf(prefix,0) === 0;
  };

  String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
  };

  String.prototype.substringBefore = function(str) {
    var idx = this.indexOf(str);
    if( idx!==-1 ) {
      return this.substr(0,idx);
    }
    return this;
  };

  String.prototype.substringBeforeLast = function(str) {
    var idx = this.lastIndexOf(str);
    if( idx!==-1 ) {
      return this.substr(0,idx);
    }
    return this;
  };

  String.prototype.substringAfter = function(str) {
    var idx = this.indexOf(str);
    if( idx!==-1 ) {
      return this.substr(idx+str.length);
    }
    return this;
  };

  String.prototype.substringAfterLast = function(str) {
    var idx = this.lastIndexOf(str);
    if( idx!==-1 ) {
      return this.substr(idx+str.length);
    }
    return this;
  };

  // left pad with spaces (or the specified character) to this length 
  String.prototype.leftPad = function (length,c) {
    c = c || " ";
    if( length <= this.length ) return this;
    return new Array(length-this.length+1).join(c) + this;
  };

  // right pad with spaces (or the specified character) to this length 
  String.prototype.rightPad = function (length,c) {
    c = c || " ";
    if( length <= this.length ) return this;
    return this + new Array(length-this.length+1).join(c);
  };
```

Comment: Modifying the prototypes is generally considered bad practice in Javascript.  These modifications aren't contained to your application in any way, so you will affect what code other libraries are using.

Comment: yes, good point. But it's so convenient for m. My (non-library) code should have the freedom to do so ? To be more precise, if I would use another library in the same HTML page, you are saying that other library's startsWith() would be modified by mode code? So if that library X makes assumptions on behaviour my prototype would change that.

Comment: Any Javascript loaded on the page is going to use the same prototypes.  There is no other "startsWith" because they're all using the same prototypes.  You can do it if you want, but you're probably better off using something like lodash, or writing function utils, to handle some of this.