# jQuery / underscore.js templating - Compatible with IE 6+?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, jquery-templates, underscore.js

So, I just learned about these recently and am about to put them into a site.  Now, the question I am posing is, does this ***at all*** throw any kid of errors in IE 6+? Yes, I know IE6, what can you do..  When I say errors, I mean IE errors / warnings.

Appreciate all the help as usual, thanks in advance.

-Wes

Comment: Have you tried it out? It's basic string manipulation to my knowledge, so I don't think you'll encounter any problems.

Comment: I've always done them in backbone, wanted to make sure it would work correctly before I moved forward.  But yes, I totally agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, yes: jQuery does work with IE6 -- it says as much on the [jQuery Homepage](http://jquery.com/) (hover over the "Cross browser" link and you'll see a popup that says IE6+). (having said that, a lot of third-party jQuery plugins are not IE6 compatible, so be careful about that)

Underscore.js I'm less certain about -- I haven't tried it on IE6, and the [Underscore.js website](http://underscorejs.org/) is not explicit about which browsers it supports. However it does include functions designed to replace functionality missing from older browsers, and IE6 is discussed in the issue tickets on github, so I would say give it a go.

Answer (score 5):

The Underscore test suite is now [here.](http://underscorejs.org/test/)

Running in on [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) results in all present tests run cleanly in IE 6 through 10, but not on IE 5.5.

I also recorded positive outcome on current Chrome 28, Opera 12 and Firefox 22.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to check this is to run the test suit on IE6 (or any browser):

- http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/test/

Comment: ietester is also useful if you don't have a 20 year old computer handy.  http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage