# Underscore.string browser support

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, underscore.string.js

[Underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) seems to provide nice features for javascript string manipulation.

It seems to have all the good points:

- license : MIT
- dependencies : none, [it is an extension for Underscore.js](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#underscorestring-) but [it can be used as standalone, without underscore.js](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#standalone-usage)
- weight (minified & gzipped): 4KB
- community, contributors: [58 contributors on Github](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/graphs/contributors)
- history, contributions: [since mid 2010 on Github, contributions seem rather stable although pretty quiet since 2014](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/graphs/contributors)

Except one point for which I am missing info: the "browser support/compatibility". I am especially worried about older version of IE.

I could find some issues (who have been fixed) on Github for various browser versions, but I could not find any clear statement regarding the browser support:

- https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/pull/37
- https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/issues?q=IE8
- https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/issues/115

I also searched on StackOverflow & did some googling but no luck.

I assume there is no "official" support for browsers so if anyone has experience in using Underscore.string in a production environment where users are on old browsers (IE8+) that would be great.

**EDIT:**

I also added a question directly on Github to try to get an answer, I'll update this page if I hear anything from there. See https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/issues/304

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by epeli [on the issue I posted on the Github project](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/issues/304): running the test suite on IE8 seems a good way to find out if this library is supported by IE8.

Hence I did so, and found out that the result was positive: IE8 is supported by Underscore.string javascript library.

See the result of my test below

[image]